# Newform opening blank for a particular SharePoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, newform, sharepoint-permissions

We are having a list in SharePoint, and for some users what we did is we only gave the Add and View permissions to the users, removing their Edit permissions on the site. So now what is happening is when we login with the same users the new form of a particular list opens blank for that user. The newly changed permissions for the users are working on the other list which I have created recently, means the user is able to view the new form for other list, but it is not working on a particular old list, where we want that user permission to work. We have made the changes for the user permissions on the site level and not on the list level. There are no unique or item level permissions applied on both the lists. Its a strange scenario. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can other users with same or different permissions see new form of the particular list?

It may be caused by broken new form of the particular list. Go to SharePoint Designer -> Files -> Find a normal list -> Copy the new form -> Paste it in the particular list -> Make sure the new form is checked in and set it as default.

Comment: Other users with different permissions can see the form, I am working on the SharePoint default new form currently

Comment: Please provide some screenshots of the custom permission for this user.

Comment: Hi Emily, Thanks for asking and for your help, actually the target audience was set to one SharePoint security group. And the logged in user was not a part of that SharePoint group. So removing the SharePoint group from target audience worked for me.

Comment: Congratulations on solving this issue and thanks for sharing your solution. You can mark the reply as the answer if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

The target audience was set to one SharePoint security group in list view web-part properties. And the logged in user was not a part of that SharePoint group. So removing the SharePoint group from target audience worked.